# Calling a function with parameter in fun main

Tags: function, kotlin, parameters

Hi could please suggest what is an issue in the below syntax. I am watching a kotlin tutorial and it is working fine in video. When I run it shows error. Thank you

```kotlin
fun ani(name: String) {
    val aaha = "hi" + name
    println(aaha)
}

fun main() {  
    ani(name: "jan")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is just a simple typo: it's `ani(name = "jan")` instead of `ani(name: "jan")`. Also, please format your future questions properly - click on "?" in the editor window for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun ani(name:String){
    val aaha="hi"+ name println(aaha) 
} 
fun main() {
   ani("jan")
}
```

Remove 'name' from ani(name:"jan")

Comment: Or use: `ani(name = "jan")`